# Checkbox not unchecking

Tags: jquery

I have this code and it works fine, but the problem is the checkbox does not get removed when you click it again, it only gets removed when the span.removePortfolio is clicked. Thanks!

```
<input type="checkbox" name="portfolio"/> 
<div>
   Has Portfolio <span class="removePortfolio">X</span>
</div>

$("input[name=portfolio]").change(function() {
    loadResults();
    checkPortStatus();
});    

$('span.removePortfolio').live("click", function() {
    $("input[name=portfolio]").removeAttr("checked");
    $('#portfolioRemove').hide();   
});

var portChecked = false;
function checkPortStatus() {
   if((portChecked) == true) {
        $("input[name=portfolio]").removeAttr("checked");
   }
}

function loadResults() {
    if($("input[name=portfolio]").attr("checked", "checked")) {
       portChecked = true;
    }

}
```

I simply need the checkbox to be checked when the user clicks it, unchecked when they click it again, and unchecked if it was checked and the user clicks the span.removePortfolio.

Comment: It's not clear what the behavior you actually want is. Also, $('#portfolioRemove').hide() refers to an element id that does not exist in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not fire the "change" event for checkboxes until the element loses focus. Use "click" instead.

Also, manipulating the "checked" property like that is not really a good idea. Use the new (since 1.6) ".prop()" method:

```
$('input.whatever').prop('checked', true);  // make the element be checked
$('input.whatever').prop('checked', false); // make it be un-checked
```

and it's probably even faster to do this (if there's just one checkbox targeted by your jQuery selector):

```
$('input.whatever')[0].checked = false; // or true
```

*edit* also, your code as written seems to want to force the checkbox to be turned off as soon as it's clicked:

1. Click the checkbox and it is (momentarily) checked
2. The "change" handler calls "loadResults()", which sets that flag ("portChecked") to true.
3. The "checkPortStatus()" function now runs, and it immediately un-checks the checkbox.

Comment: ok interesting, but I am not having this issue with IE...haven't even checked IE yet...using FF

Comment: OK well see my answer - the "checked" property is, well, a **property** and not an attribute when you're dealing with the DOM.